# Static member called MinBalance is not working as required

Tags: c#

This is my class:

```
class EmpDetails
{
    private string _EmpName;
    private int _EmpID;
    private string _EmpDepartment;
    private string _EmpPosition;
    private decimal _Balance;
    private static int _PrevId;

    public static decimal MinBalance; //This memeber is not working as required


    **public void Withdraw(decimal amount) // The Problem is in this method**
    {
        if (this.Balance < MinBalance)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Insufficient funds");
        }
        else
        {
            this._Balance -= amount;
        }
    }
}
```

I have highlighted the method called `Withdraw` which I think is creating a problem. It is suppose to check if the balance is less than Minimum balance and throw an exception. Lets say when I set the MinBalance to 500 and Balance to 1000 and then try to withdraw 600 out of 1000 then it should throw an exception saying insufficient balance, but it is not working in the first go but rather working when I try to withdraw the second time.

Comment: `You don't have to put everything in code blocks`

Comment: Please (1)  be more specific about what you mean by "not working", and (2) delete all the code that is unrelated to the problem. Reduce your program to the smallest possible program that still has the problem. For example, the `EmpDepartment` appears to have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Have you tried qualifying MinBalance with class name all the time.

Comment: @Tilak Yes I qualified MinBalance with Class name as it is a Static member

Comment: When you are exactly sure where the problem is, just go ahead and fix it. SO is not a free “do it for me” debugging service. The bug in your code is trivial.

Comment: Check my answer, i think that is your problem. And please mark it as answer if it solves your problem, thanks.

Comment: @OndrejTucny As I have mentioned that the MinBalance might be causing the problem. If I know the exact answer then why I post the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to check not your currente Balance but how your Balance will be **after** you Withdraw, thats why it is not working as you expect, you can do it like this:

```
public void Withdraw(decimal amount) // The Problem is in this method**
{
    if ( ( this.Balance - amount ) < MinBalance)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Insufficient funds");
    }
    else
    {
        this._Balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you step through your code, you'll see the problem. Set a breakpoint on the line `if (this.Balance < MinBalance)`. The first time through, the balance (1000) is higher than the minimum balance (600), so the withdrawal is allowed. It sounds like you really want to check the remaining balance, not the starting balance.

Answer (score 1):

IF I understand your description of the problem right, you want to block people from reducing your balance to below your min balance.

```
    public void Withdraw(decimal amount) // The Problem is in this method**
    {
        if (this.Balance < MinBalance)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Insufficient funds");
        }
        else
        {
            this._Balance -= amount;
        }
    }
```

But you're not factoring the withdrawal into that equation.  change your condition to

```
if (this.Balance - amount < MinBalance)
{
```